# React Admin: onSuccess does not work properly on <Edit> Component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

`onSuccess` function does not work properly on `react-admin`,

my code:

```js
const onSuccess = () => {
   redirect('list', props.basePath);
};


<Edit 
  onFailure={onFailure}  
  onSuccess={onSuccess}  
  title="Ediar Usuário" 
  {...props} 
>
  <SimpleForm 
     variant="standard" 
     toolbar={<CustomToolbar />} 
  >
</Edit>
```

On the first time, it works perfectly but at second time, nothing happens.

Do not even trigger the save event

Comment: Hi, would you kindly explain what you are trying to achieve? By default, once edit is finished the form redirects to the list view.

Comment: What version of react-admin are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is applicable to your use case but setting `undoable` to false on `Edit` component works

Answer (score 1):

I am suffering from the same problem.

Jasper Bernales's tip was effective.

I've changed my code from :

```
<Edit
      onSuccess={onSuccess}
      {...props}
    >
```

to :

```
<Edit
      onSuccess={onSuccess}
      undoable={false}
      {...props}
    >
```

then ...it works!

It seems like a problem caused by forcing "useRedirect" or "useRefresh" to interfere with the delay scheduled by "undoable".The document seems to need an update to this part. just check this out from React-Admin Docs.:

> You can disable this behavior by setting undoable={false}. With that
> setting, clicking on the Delete button displays a confirmation dialog.
> Both the Save and the Delete actions **become blocking and delay the    refresh of the screen until the data provider responds.**

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue I came across this [issue](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/5785) on the `react-admin` github page. So basically it is not a bug but ... kinda feature the way the `Edit` component works. In short:

```
const onSuccess = () => {
     ...
     notify('success', 'info', null, true);
     ...
}
```

This is the way you should call notify inside your custom `onSuccess` function to trigger the real update on the `dataProvider`.